# Call a template from html with default router param in URL

Tags: html, meteor, iron-router

I have an iron route for template "eventContainer" which includes a parameter according to which event the user have selected in previous templates.

```
Router.route ('/eventContainer/:_id', {
  template: "/eventContainer",
  data: function(){      
}});
```

This is working fine.  When the user login the second time, I load as his homepage  the "eventContainer" template but I'm looking for a way to set a route parameter  since the handlebars event calling. (The param should be the last event they had seen).

There is a way to call a template from html using double braces  `{{> eventContainer}}` with a route parameter?  Something like `{{> eventContainer RouterParam:xx}}`?.

```
<template name="home">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{#if notEventJoined}}
      {{> findEvent}}
    {{else}}
      {{> eventContainer}}
    {{/if}}
  {{else}}
  Loading...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

and...

```
<template name="eventContainer">
  <!-- Here I read the Router.current().params._id -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass helper as parameter:

```html
<template name="home">
    {{> eventContainer param}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.home.helpers({
  param: function() {
    return Router.current().params._id;
  }
});
```

Comment: In your example param helper returns undefined because there isn't a route param in the home path.  I changed the param helper query to get the last event joined (stored in some collection) but the call {{> eventContainer param}} don't go to the route specified in param.  Probably because eventContainer is being loaded inside from home path.

Comment: You have a route for `eventContainer` template, but does user actually go to `/eventContainer` and see such template? As I can see you embed this template in existsting one, so there are more convinience ways to handle data flow.